# Is there a command in MySQL equivalent to the "do repeat" command in SPSS?

Tags: mysql, sql, spss, case-when

I have to write essentially the same `CASE WHEN`-statement for a number of columns, let's say price_1 to price_30. Instead of having to copy paste the statement for all 30 columns, is there a way to use something equivalent to the "do repeat" command in SPSS?

E.g. I need to write:

```
price_1=CASE WHEN price_1 < 30 THEN NULL ELSE price_1 END,
price_2=CASE WHEN price_2 < 30 THEN NULL ELSE price_2 END,
..
price_30=CASE WHEN price_30 < 30 THEN NULL ELSE price_30 END.
```

But would like to write something like this in MySQL:

price_1-price_30=CASE WHEN price_ < 30 THEN NULL ELSE price_ END.

I have tried to search online but seem to only find loop commands where the updates happen over time?

I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  Comparing a *descriptive* language like SQL to a procedural language such as SPSS is generally not very helpful.

Comment: Do you mean variables (as in procedural code) or do you actually mean _columns_ in a table? If it's columns in a table, then having price_1 to price_30 is usually a sign of a bad data model that should be normalized and the prices should be stored in rows, not in columns

Comment: Sorry, I mean columns in a table. price_1 is a column, price_2 is a column etc. Maybe it's a bad data model, but it's not something I can change.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, perhaps (if using MYSQL) you are looking for the REPEAT() function? If so, here is an example:

```
SELECT REPEAT("customerName", 3);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have tried to edit the original post to be more clear. I think in your example the name of the customer will be repeated thrice? I wanted a command where I don't have to write the same CASE WHEN command many times in a row, just editing the name of the variable, but rather a single CASE WHEN command that includes all the variables. I am pretty new to SQL so not sure how to word it in the right way!